# How to trigger any event for dynamic element?

Tags: javascript, events

I have this one:

```
function fillCard()
{
    const persons = document.getElementsByClassName("fillCard");
    if(persons !== null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
        {
            persons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var getUrl = this.getAttribute("href");
                var url = new URL(location.origin + getUrl);
                var Id = url.searchParams.get("id");
                fetch(getUrl + "&id=" + Id + "&do=fillCard")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById("frm-newCard-lastname").value = data[0];
                    document.getElementById("frm-newCard-firstname").value = data[1];
                    document.getElementById("frm-newCard-dateofbirth").value = data[2];
                    document.getElementById("frm-newCard-phone_number").value = data[3];
                    document.getElementsByName("identifier")[0].value = data[4];
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is - those elements with class name **fillCard** are created dynamically by AJAX. The event listener does not work then. How to trigger the event properly? Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Attach the event listener _after_ the elements are created

Comment: @JeremyThille How? I realize there is several topics with the same problem, but I'm not able to understand.

Comment: Well I have no idea how they are created, so I can't tell

Comment: @JeremyThille I have added some more code.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code in it, don't answer your own question. Besides, what you have added is not an ajax call, it's a template. You said the elements were created with an ajax call

Comment: Unfortunately this code is too long.

Yes, it's template, but the code inside **snippet** is created by ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function fillCard()
{
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if(!e.target.matches('.fillCard'))
            return;
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var getUrl = e.target.getAttribute("href");
        var url = new URL(location.origin + getUrl);
        var Id = url.searchParams.get("id");
        fetch(getUrl + "&id=" + Id + "&do=fillCard")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById("frm-newCard-lastname").value = data[0];
            document.getElementById("frm-newCard-firstname").value = data[1];
            document.getElementById("frm-newCard-dateofbirth").value = data[2];
            document.getElementById("frm-newCard-phone_number").value = data[3];
            document.getElementsByName("identifier")[0].value = data[4];
        });
    });
}
```